# After Insert Trigger WIth MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, trigger

I think I have all my bases covered but wanted to ask someone who knows better than I.  This is my syntax.

```
UPDATE SI
SET autoInsert = 0
FROM inserted
WHERE SI.autoInsert = SI.autoInsert
OR SI.autoInsert IS NULL;
```

and I want to set `autoInsert = 0` where `autoInsert = 1` or `autoInsert IS NULL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you have some sort of identity or unique key column on your `SI` table. (This will be a little more difficult if you haven't.)

I'm also going to assume your `autoInsert` column is a BIT data type. This means the only values we can possibly have are 1, 0 or NULL. And you want the value updated to 0.

And finally, I'm going to assume you only care about updates to the `autoInsert` column.

If that's all true, try this:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER dbo.trg_ZeroAutoInsert
    ON dbo.SI
AFTER UPDATE
AS
UPDATE          dbo.SI
SET             autoInsert = 0
FROM            dbo.SI
    INNER JOIN  inserted AS i
        ON      SI.id = i.id ;
```

If, however, your `autoInsert` column is an INT (or similar) data type, you can add the where clause to only cover values of 1 or NULL:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER dbo.trg_ZeroAutoInsert
    ON dbo.SI
AFTER UPDATE
AS
UPDATE          dbo.SI
SET             autoInsert = 0
FROM            dbo.SI
    INNER JOIN  inserted AS i
        ON      SI.id = i.id
WHERE           i.autoInsert = 1
    OR          i.autoInsert IS NULL ;
```

Comment: Wow, sorry I did not realize all of those caveats about a ``Trigger``  - your assumption is correct ``autoInsert`` is a ``bit`` datatype and the table does have a ``Primary Key``